# see a .pdf with the <object> tag not loads in firefox or other way to achieve

Tags: angular

I am using the latest version of firefox and the pdf that I am trying to load are not displayed. In chrome, my code does work, but I'm not sure if I'm forgetting some additional configuration for firefox to show me the PDFs.

how can I solve that?

this is my code:

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
} 

<object *ngIf="pdf" [data]="pdf | safe" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
<p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: 
<a href=".pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
</object>

<button (click)="loadPdf1()">Load Pdf 1</button>
<button (click)="loadPdf2()">Load Pdf 2</button>  

loadPdf1(){
  this.pdf="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
}
loadPdf2(){
  this.pdf="https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf"
}
```

this is the response on the console web

[image]

Or what else can I do to load a PDF in Firefox without installing an additional library?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19b9ne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Do you see any error in browser or console in FF?

Comment: @nircraft I updated the question with the response on the console of firefox, or what is FF?

Comment: FF is FireFox..

Comment: @nircraft oh... works my code for you????

Comment: i am sorry, i do not have Firefox in my machine. Works fine in Chrome though and those erorr screenshots do not make any sense.